# Restrict file uploading to bucket root (pre-signed Form)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to restrict the file upload via [html forms (pre-signed POST)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTForms.html) to the root folder?

The docs describes uploading into a specific folder with the `starts-with` condition.
But I can't see a way to restrict uploading to the bucket root (or any specific folder, without the ability to generate additional subfolders).

This bucket is only for uploading and any files that are accepted will move into another bucket. Because of that I don't want folders in there....

Answer (score 0):

You will need an S3 Policy to deny actions where the resource contains a /.  Add this to your S3 Bucket resource policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyObjectOthers",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```